# What is the best way to generate/trigger child events when using AWS Eventbridge and Step Functions?

Tags: aws-step-functions, aws-event-bridge

It's quite a common requirement in business processing for one step to trigger a number of child processes (which often need some high-level oversight).  For example, a request trigger comes in to distribute a report;  Step 1 identifies who the report should be distributed to and triggers a separate process to generate and distribute the report for each recipient; and once all the reports have been distributed the parent process responds to the original request with a delivery report.

What is the best way to handle this using AWS Eventbridge and Step Functions?  Are there recognised best practices?